# In the TV show Revolution, where does Georgia get its ammo?

Tags: revolution

Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40842/why-could-they-not-make-bullets-without-power). If ammunition for modern guns cannot be produced without electricity, then where does the Georgian Federation get its ammo?

In the beginning of the show we see the Monroe militia use cross-bows and flit-lock muskets, because their modern ammo supplies have run low, and they cannot make more without electricity. Yet in the second half of the first season, both the militia and the Georgian Federation seem to have plenty of ammo for their M-16s. It is conceivable that Monroe can use the pendants and the amplifiers to start making new ammo, but what about Georgia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Five years after the blackout, the Monroe Militia had a series of battles known as the Trenton Campaign. It was after this conflict that they realized ammunition was becoming short in supply and would have to be rationed.

> This was notable as being one of the last battles that the Militia fought with modern weapons like M9 pistols and M4 carbines before they had to start rationing modern ammunition. - [Revolution Wiki](http://revolution.wikia.com/wiki/Trenton_campaign)

Inside Philadelphia, particularly with Monroe's guards or elite soldiers, you see them using modern weapons with ammunition. Miles at one point replies that some of the weapons must have come from the Philadelphia armory.

**It is possible that the Georgia Republic (with its own cache of weapons) didn't have as many conflicts as the Monroe Militia and thus was about to save more ammunition.**

There are also armories and weapon depots scattered throughout the United States. If the various government entities found them, they could resupply their stock pile.  It was also shown that Monroe was stockpiling weapons in ammunition in Philadelphia

Comment: I guess this is the best explanation we are likely to get. Although, I still find it hard to believe that the was enough weapons and ammo in those depots to last 15 years.

Comment: @Dima considering a lot of the people died of starvation and exposure for the first couple of years, there are a lot more guns and ammo to go around.